# Check Point Firewall monitoring with zabbix

Tags: monitoring, firewall, snmp, zabbix, checkpoint

I am trying to get my Check Point 1550 appliance setup to be monitored by Zabbix. I am really struggling getting the SNMP to work. Does anyone know of a method to get this working? My appliance does not have a CLI so I cannot install anything on it and I do not have a license for SMS or anything.

Question might sound strange but I'm under the impression that SNMP and zabbig does not work out of the box.

Comment: Zabbix can read SNMP out of the box, if you install the packaged version, or if you compile it using `--with-net-snmp`. Try using `snmpwalk` to manually read SNMP values in order to verify that CheckPoint configuration is correct.